# Ip filtering on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am running a container exposed to internet end secured using client certificates. To be able to accept incoming calls without credentials I want to run a second container that accepts calls from one static ip and forwards the request to the first container.
How do I setup ip filtering for the second container? Can I run both containers in one pod or do i need two separate pods?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, LoadBalancer supports [IP filtering](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/#restrict-access-for-loadbalancer-service) and you can use [selectors](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service#what_is_a_service) to target specific pods, but i don't think you can target specific containers, so you will need to run two pods. LoadBalancer configuration will look something like this.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: myapp
spec:
    ports:
    - port: 8765
        targetPort: 9376
    selector:
    app: example
    type: LoadBalancer
    loadBalancerSourceRanges:
    - 130.211.204.1/32
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out